# SQL Editor Query Java Object saved into VARBINARY column

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jpa, varbinary

I have a 'varbinary' column where a java Properties object (Extends Hashtable) is being saved in the binary format. If I just query and convert to VARCHAR the value I get is still an un-queryble format

`select CAST(myBinaryColumn AS VARCHAR(max)) from myTable;`

The result is something like:

`¬ísrjava.util.Properties9Ðzp6>˜LdefaultstLjava/util/Properties;xrjava.util.Hashtable»%!Jä¸F loadFactorI thresholdxp?@wttot9999.99tfromt0.0xp`

How do I convert this into something usable in a query or at least human readable?

Comment: The reverse of however you save it...

Comment: To expand on Dale's comment: it's however Java decided to serialize it to binary, you'd need to deserialize it in Java code again to extract the meaningful information. If you need to consume the data inside SQL Server consider serializing it to JSON or XML instead.

Comment: If you want to both store it as a Java object and read it on the server with queries, you'll need the Java language extension. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/language-extensions/java-overview?view=sql-server-ver16